VueJs can not fetch data from C# web api session
I have a problem with fetching data from C# web api session. Problem occurs only, when I try to fetch from https://localhost:8080 (vue js port) to my api (https://localhost:7251).
When I use insomnia/swagger it looks perfectly fine.
Here is code for Vue.js fetch:
<script>
import axios from "axios";

export default {
  // eslint-disable-next-line vue/multi-word-component-names
  name: "Header",
  data() {
    return {
      user: {}, // Domyślnie pusty obiekt dla użytkownika
    };
  },
  methods: {
    async getUser() {
      try {
        const result = await axios.get(
          "https://localhost:7251/api/Auths/GetUser",
          {
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/json",
            },
            withCredentials: true, // Włącza obsługę ciasteczek dla sesji
            mode: "cors", // Wyraźnie określa, że żądanie jest między domenami
          }
        );
        console.log("RESULT: ", result);
        if (result.status === 200) {
          console.warn("USER DATA: ", result.data);
          this.user = result.data; // Zakładamy, że result.data ma właściwość 'name'
        } else {
          console.error("Failed to fetch user data");
        }
      } catch (error) {
        console.error(
          "Error fetching user data:",
          error.response?.data || error.message
        );
      }
    },
  },
  mounted() {
    this.getUser(); // Wywołanie funkcji przy montowaniu komponentu
  },
};
</script>

And thats vue.config.js:
const { defineConfig } = require("@vue/cli-service");

module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  devServer: {
    https: true, // Włącza HTTPS
    allowedHosts: "all",
  },
});

This is project setup on Program.cs file:
Cors policy:
builder.Services.AddCors(options =>
{
    options.AddPolicy("AllowAllOrigins", policy =>
    {
        policy.WithOrigins("https://localhost:8080")// Domena frontendu
              .AllowAnyHeader()
              .AllowAnyMethod()
              .AllowCredentials(); // Umożliwia przesyłanie ciasteczek/sesji
    });
});
app.UseCors("AllowAllOrigins");

And session:
builder.Services.AddSingleton<IHttpContextAccessor, HttpContextAccessor>();
builder.Services.AddDistributedMemoryCache();
builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
{
    options.Cookie.Name = "Session.Works";
    options.IdleTimeout = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30); // Czas wygasniecia sesji
    options.Cookie.IsEssential = true; // Sesje beda dzialaly nawet bez zgody na cookies
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.None;     // Pozwala na prawidlowe przekazywanie ciasteczka
    //options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.SameAsRequest;

});

All I get while fetching from session is "Session could not retrive user" and 500 Internal server error.
It happens ONLY on client side, login/register calls work fine.
What should I do ?

with credentialed requests you cannot wildcard origins, headers or methods. (or expose-headers)  Can you include the CORS exception that the browser reports?  There may also be a server problem responding to OPTIONS request, or the order of app.UseCors is incorrect.  See here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware/?view=aspnetcore-9.0#middleware-order

Problem was the order of Program.cs file:
app.UseCookiePolicy();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors("AllowVueApp");
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseSession();
app.MapControllers();```

Problem solved.
Error was created because of order in Program.cs file, correct order is:
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.UseCookiePolicy();
app.UseRouting();
app.UseCors("AllowVueApp");
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();
app.UseSession();
app.MapControllers();

